# считать файл с определенного места си

Tags: c++, c

можно ли начать читать файл с определенного места?например есть текст,обработал одно слово -закрыл файл,в другой функции открыл этот файл и начать читать следующее слово?искал ответ так и не нашел

Comment: функция fseek есть

Comment: Всё-таки Си или Си++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пример использования функции fseek

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  FILE * ptrFile = fopen( "example.txt" , "w" );

  fputs( "This is sample." , ptrFile );       // записать в файл строку
  fseek( ptrFile , 9 , SEEK_SET );            // изменить позицию на 9 байт относительно начала файла
  fputs( "parta" , ptrFile );                 // дописать слово в файл
  fclose ( ptrFile );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то лучше не `"w"`, а `"wb"` - а то откроет как текстовый. И еще - `<iostream>` тут совсем не надо, да и лучше уж для языка C использовать `<stdio.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас C++ (в тэгах он стоит!), то нужно пользоваться потоками.

```
ifstream in("example.txt");
in.seekg(10,ios::beg);

int n;
in.read(&n,sizeof(int));
```

Что-то вроде этого. Смотрите функции `seekg` и `seekp`.